# ImportError: No module named 'twitter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

First file i'm trying to install an external package - twitter 1.14.3 (on windows 7)

so i downloaded the package to c:\python33\twitter-1.14.3,

then i run:

```
python.exe c:\python33\twitter-1.14.3\setup.py install

Finished processing..
```

Now i'm trying to use that new module:

```
from twitter import *
```

and i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test1.py", line 1, in <module>
\ufefffrom twitter import *
ImportError: No module named 'twitter'
```

When i'm trying to run the twitter.exe, i get:

```
c:\Python33\Scripts>twitter.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\Scripts\twitter-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('twitter==1.14.3', 'console_scripts', 'twitter')()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ImportError: No module named 'twitter'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks/

Comment: why don't you use pip ? so you can do "pip freeze" and see what is installed and what not.

Comment: c:\Python33\Scripts>pip freeze    
twitter==1.14.3

Comment: c:\Python33\Scripts>twitter.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\Scripts\twitter-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('twitter==1.14.3', 'console_scripts', 'twitter')()

Comment: Do you have python2.x installed on machine? It looks like you have installed twitter module for python2.x. Try `python3.exe c:\python33\twitter-1.14.3\setup.py install`

Comment: yup, i have python32 on another folder, but i've installed the twitter using the right python.exe (under c:\python33. i have no "python3.exe" on any folder.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your friendly neighborhood Command Prompt and type in the following:

```
pip install twitter
```

It should say something along the lines of "Installing collected packages... Successfully installed twitter-1.18.0"

Then run from your IDE:

```
import twitter  # work with Twitter APIs
```

And proceed with setting up your API keys